# Get response from EXECUTE in PLPGSQL

Tags: postgresql, azure-sql-database, azure-postgresql

I have set up a small query that uses a DO block to dynamically edit multiple tables.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    _table varchar[];
    loop_item text;
BEGIN
    SELECT array_agg(table_name::TEXT) FROM information_schema.tables 
    INTO _table
    WHERE table_schema = 'public';

FOREACH loop_item IN ARRAY "_table" 
LOOP
    IF loop_item != 'test' THEN     
        EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %s
        ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS new_column varchar;', loop_item);
    END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
$$
```

If the EXECUTE statement is not executed, a notice is printed. But I would also like to know when it was executed successfully.
How can I capture and RAISE the return message of the EXECUTE statement?

Info: I am using the Azure Database for Postgres and have no access to the config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raise a `NOTICE`:

```
IF loop_item != 'test' THEN     
    EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I
        ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS new_column varchar;', loop_item);
    RAISE NOTICE 'Table %s altered', loop_item;
END IF;
```

Your original code is vulnerable to SQL injection, and you should use the `%I` format.

Comment: My question was inaccurate. This works for ALTER TABLE, but I am interested if it is possible to grab the output of e.g. a SELECT or INSERT and then raise it? So I can run one query conveniently on many tables.

Comment: `EXECUTE 'SELECT ...' INTO record_var; RAISE '%', to_json(record_var);`